# Having Multiple Setup Resources Under SQL Folder

Tags: setup-script, resource-model

Is it appropriate if maintaining the structure of setup resources folder structure as below ?

```
MyModule > Helper
           sql    > mymodule_customer_setup
                  > mymodule_directory_setup
                  > mymodule_setup
```

If above structure is fine, then how should I define in the config.xml? I am thinking to define like below:

```
<resources>
    <mymodule_customer_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Package_MyModule</module>
        </setup>
    </mymodule_customer_setup>
    <mymodule_directory_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Package_MyModule</module>
        </setup>
    </mymodule_directory_setup>
    <mymodule_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Package_MyModule</module>
        </setup>
    </mymodule_setup>
</resources>
```

Comment: The best way to find out is to test it and see the results. in my opinion it should work since the config.xml files are merged into one big config.

Comment: Marius, you are right, they are working. But after looking at the config.xml, maintaining the script version in sequence might be difficult.

Comment: Yep. That might be a side effect.

Comment: What is the reason for trying to separate them? If they can be logically separated you could put each into an extension of its own.

Comment: There are reasons you might need multiple for a single module. I have used two in the past in order to have one setup script that works on an external database and one that works on the main database. If the separation is purely because each resource is used by different elements for overloading different core module functionality, I agree it makes sense to have multiple extensions.

Comment: As wish to keep the version in sequence, eventually we decided to put all scripts into one. And previously, the reason we created multiple extensions simply for us to easy identify if that setup script would be impacted to which core module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's step through what actually happens here.

**Install scripts for all.**

I created update scripts for all three resources and then in the `core_resource` table you get the following information.

```
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
| code                     | version | data_version |
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
| mymodule_customer_setup  | 0.7.0   | 0.7.0        |
| mymodule_directory_setup | 0.7.0   | 0.7.0        |
| mymodule_setup           | 0.7.0   | 0.7.0        |
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
```

**Updates for one script**

I then update the version id of the config but include only one update script.

```
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
| code                     | version | data_version |
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
| mymodule_customer_setup  | 0.7.1   | 0.7.1        |
| mymodule_directory_setup | 0.7.1   | 0.7.1        |
| mymodule_setup           | 0.7.1   | 0.7.1        |
+--------------------------+---------+--------------+
```

So sadly as expected all the resources get updated at the same time even with only the one script :(

Technically there is nothing wrong with this approach, I have tested it and each script does get called but all version numbers get updated at the same time. It might look a bit odd having "missing" scripts in your directories but you could always put empty scripts there that simply start and end setup so as to keep the order.